# Create Fraction in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fractions

I have been given a task at school to define a function name "fraction", work just as the Fraction Modules.
Here is how I do it:

```
def GCD(x,y):
  while y!= 0:
    (x,y) =(y,x%y)
  return x  
def fraction(a,b):
  a/=GCD(a,b)
  b/=GCD(a,b)
  print(str(int(a))+"/"+str(int(b)))
```

But when I tried to see how it'd work, it became like this:

```
fraction(45,9)
5/9
```

I don't know where I was wrong, can someone help me to figure it out?
Thank you so much.

Comment: This is not a solution to your problem, but for someone else (& maybe the OP also), if someone is wondering about the part `work just as the Fraction Modules`, it would work so, `print(Fraction(45, 9))` gives the output `5`.

Comment: You're modifying `a/=GCD(a,b)` before using it to calculate `b/=FCD(a,b)`.
Just use `x=GCD(a,b)` as an intermediate measure, and use `x` to calculate `a`, and `b`. Then, it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your def fraction,

```
def fraction(a,b):
  a/=GCD(a,b)
  b/=GCD(a,b)
  print(str(int(a))+"/"+str(int(b)))
```

You modified a. a became 45/9 = 5. b divided by GCD(5,9) (which equals 1) will just be b. Instead, you could store the GCD in a temporary variable and divide both by it.

```
 def fraction(a,b):
  gcd = GCD(a,b)
  a//=gcd
  b//=gcd
  print(str(int(a))+"/"+str(int(b)))
```

Answer (score 2):

you modify `a` before you calculate the `GCD` for `b`; your second `GCD` calculation will therefore always return `1`.

you could try this:

```
def fraction(a,b):
  g = GCD(a,b)
  a //= g
  b //= g
  print("{}/{}".format(a, b))
```

also note that i used [integer division (floordiv) `//`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) so i do not get a float as result that i have to cast back to in `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your helpful answers, I've realized what I did wrong and make a new one combining all your answers.
Here is the new one:

```
def GCD(x,y):
  while y!= 0:
    (x,y) =(y,x%y)
  return x  
def fraction(a,b):
  gcd=GCD(a,b)
  a=a//gcd
  b=b//gcd
  print(str(a)+"/"+str(b))
```

Thank you all so so much again, you have made my day.